# Repeated SIGILL/SIGSEGV Errors from Software on Archlinux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, x86-64

Different pieces of software often crash on my OS which is Arch Linux btw. Most common crashes come from individual chrome pages or visual studio code which show SIGSEGV or SIGILL error codes.

Looking at log, I see:

```
Process 11754 (chrome) of user 1000 dumped core.
...
Stack trace of thread 11754:
#0  0x000055ab8581628b n/a (chrome + 0x6a7228b)
#1  0x000055ab8141f8c5 n/a (chrome + 0x267b8c5)
#2  0x000055ab8141aaa8 n/a (chrome + 0x2676aa8)
#3  0x000055ab81408a12 n/a (chrome + 0x2664a12)
#4  0x000055ab814015f9 n/a (chrome + 0x265d5f9)
#5  0x000055ab8384f58c n/a (chrome + 0x4aab58c)
#6  0x000055ab810c9c40 n/a (chrome + 0x2325c40)
#7  0x000055ab810c8834 n/a (chrome + 0x2324834)
#8  0x000055ab838cc1ee n/a (chrome + 0x4b281ee)
#9  0x000055ab8291c5f8 n/a (chrome + 0x3b785f8)
#10 0x000055ab8291bc9e n/a (chrome + 0x3b77c9e)
#11 0x000055ab8128fdff n/a (chrome + 0x24ebdff)
#12 0x000055ab8294f0a0 n/a (chrome + 0x3bab0a0)
#13 0x000055ab826dfbb2 n/a (chrome + 0x393bbb2)
#14 0x000055ab826dd268 ChromeMain (chrome + 0x3939268)
#15 0x00007f09fe96f290 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x23290)
#16 0x00007f09fe96f34a __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2334a)
#17 0x000055ab83a7e53a _start (chrome + 0x4cda53a)
...
Stack trace of thread 11756:
#0  0x00007f09fe9cf4b6 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x834b6)
#1  0x00007f09fe9d1fd4 pthread_cond_timedwait (libc.so.6 + 0x85fd4)
#2  0x000055ab8123a1f2 n/a (chrome + 0x24961f2)
#3  0x000055ab81239d91 n/a (chrome + 0x2495d91)
#4  0x000055ab81239407 n/a (chrome + 0x2495407)
#5  0x000055ab81238c3d n/a (chrome + 0x2494c3d)
#6  0x000055ab82622fa3 n/a (chrome + 0x387efa3)
#7  0x00007f09fe9d28fd n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x868fd)
#8  0x00007f09fea54a60 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x108a60)
ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
```

Could the issue is that ELF assumes the AMD architecture however my system has an intel CPU? If so, how would I solve this problem? If not, how should I procede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Different pieces of software often crash on my OS which is Arch Linux

When random existing programs crash on a given system with `SIGSEGV` and `SIGILL`, the most likely cause is faulty RAM.

Run [memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/) for a few hours, and chances are it will detect that your memory is having problems.

> Could the issue is that ELF assumes the AMD architecture however my system has an intel CPU?

No. `amd64` is the code name for `x86_64` architecture, and both Intel and AMD implementations of that architecture work just fine.